# Postfix instances sporadically processing other instances incoming emails

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I have a server with Postfix multi instances setup on it, with each instance having its own IP:

1. instance 1: example.com (root domain with mailboxes for bounce/fbl ad-hoc processing)
2. instance 2: unsub.eg.example.com (sub domain with mailboxes for unsub processing)
3. instance 3: out1.eg.example.com (outbound only)
4. instance 4: out2.eg.example.com (outbound only)

Everything works fine as far as sending out emails, or receiving emails on domain unsub.eg.example.com.

However, when sending an email to test@example.com or bounce@example.com...any of the four instances could process it, not only example.com instance. When picked up by unsub, out1 or out2 a NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from : 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; error is logged by the processing instance. if instance 1 happens to pick it up, it gets delivered to mailbox no problem.

So it's driving me crazy why the other instances are picking up an email bound for example.com

The following are highlight configurations for main.cf for instances, that I believe could be causing issue:

**smtp.example.com**

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-smtp
command_directory=/usr/sbin
daemon_directory=/usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory=/var/lib/postfix-smtp
mail_owner=postfix
syslog_name=pfix-smtp

myhostname=smtp.example.com
mydomain=example.com
myorigin=$mydomain
inet_interfaces=$myhostname
inet_protocols=ipv4
mydestination=localhost
mynetworks_style=host
relay_domains=
relayhost=

home_mailbox=Maildir/
disable_vrfy_command=yes
virtual_mailbox_domains=$mydomain
virtual_mailbox_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes
smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtpd_recipients_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_sasl_local_domain
local_recipient_maps=$alias_maps,$virtual_mailbox_maps
```

---

**unsub.eg.example.com**

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-unsub
command_directory=/usr/sbin
daemon_directory=/usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory=/var/lib/postfix-unsub
mail_owner=postfix
syslog_name=pfix-unsub

myhostname=unsub.eg.example.com
mydomain=unsub.eg.example.com
myorigin=$mydomain
inet_interfaces=$myhostname
inet_protocols=ipv4
mydestination=localhost
mynetworks_style=host
relay_domains=
relayhost=

home_mailbox=Maildir/
disable_vrfy_command=yes
virtual_mailbox_domains=$myhostname
virtual_mailbox_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_alias_maps=hash:/etc/postfix-unsub/virtual

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes
smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtpd_recipients_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_sasl_local_domain=
local_recipient_maps=$alias_maps,$virtual_mailbox_maps
```

---

**out1.eg.example.com**

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-ou1
command_directory=/usr/sbin
daemon_directory=/usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory=/var/lib/postfix-ou1
mail_owner=postfix
syslog_name=pfix-out1

myhostname=out1.eg.example.com
mydomain=out1.eg.example.com
myorigin=$mydomain
inet_interfaces=$myhostname
inet_protocols=ipv4
mydestination=
mynetworks_style=host
relay_domains=
relayhost=
```

---

**out2.eg.example.com**

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-ou2
command_directory=/usr/sbin
daemon_directory=/usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory=/var/lib/postfix-ou2
mail_owner=postfix
syslog_name=pfix-out2

myhostname=out2.eg.example.com
mydomain=out2.eg.example.com
myorigin=$mydomain
inet_interfaces=$myhostname
inet_protocols=ipv4
mydestination=
mynetworks_style=host
relay_domains=
relayhost=
```

Note: I have also generated self signed tls certificates and dkim signature for all instances, however things look fine and I don't think these could be a culprit.

Thanks buckets everyone!

**9/25/2014 Logs:** These are the logs I got today from testing sending email using an outlook client:

```
Sep 25 06:04:37 bm1 pfix-out2/anvil[11131]: statistics: max connection rate 3/60s for (smtp:XXX.XXX.XXX.42) at Sep 25 06:01:12
Sep 25 06:04:37 bm1 pfix-out2/anvil[11131]: statistics: max connection count 3 for (smtp:XXX.XXX.XXX.42) at Sep 25 06:01:12
Sep 25 06:04:37 bm1 pfix-out2/anvil[11131]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Sep 25 06:01:01
Sep 25 06:05:46 bm1 pfix-out1/anvil[11191]: statistics: max connection rate 3/60s for (smtp:XXX.XXX.XXX.42) at Sep 25 06:02:21
Sep 25 06:05:46 bm1 pfix-out1/anvil[11191]: statistics: max connection count 3 for (smtp:XXX.XXX.XXX.42) at Sep 25 06:02:21
Sep 25 06:05:46 bm1 pfix-out1/anvil[11191]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Sep 25 06:02:10
Sep 25 06:06:11 bm1 pfix-unsub/smtpd[11239]: connect from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:06:11 bm1 pfix-unsub/smtpd[11239]: setting up TLS connection from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:06:11 bm1 pfix-unsub/smtpd[11239]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]: TLSv1 with cipher ADH-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Sep 25 06:06:11 bm1 pfix-unsub/smtpd[11239]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]: 554 5.7.1 <fbl@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<m.mokhtar@sender.com> to=<fbl@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<sender.com>
Sep 25 06:06:11 bm1 pfix-unsub/smtpd[11239]: disconnect from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: connect from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: setting up TLS connection from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]: TLSv1 with cipher ADH-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: D91BB3060289: client=mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/cleanup[11260]: D91BB3060289: message-id=<004001cfd886$d01b96c0$7052c440$@mokhtar@sender.com>
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 opendkim[18460]: D91BB3060289: mail.sender.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.250] not internal
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 opendkim[18460]: D91BB3060289: not authenticated
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 opendkim[18460]: D91BB3060289: no signature data
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/qmgr[7018]: D91BB3060289: from=<m.mokhtar@sender.com>, size=11502, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: disconnect from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/virtual[11261]: D91BB3060289: to=<bounce@example.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.09, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Sep 25 06:07:02 bm1 pfix-smtp/qmgr[7018]: D91BB3060289: removed
Sep 25 06:07:46 bm1 pfix-smtp/anvil[11102]: statistics: max connection rate 3/60s for (smtp:XXX.XXX.XXX.42) at Sep 25 06:02:23
Sep 25 06:07:46 bm1 pfix-smtp/anvil[11102]: statistics: max connection count 3 for (smtp:XXX.XXX.XXX.42) at Sep 25 06:02:23
Sep 25 06:07:46 bm1 pfix-smtp/anvil[11102]: statistics: max cache size 2 at Sep 25 06:02:12
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: connect from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: setting up TLS connection from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]: TLSv1 with cipher ADH-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: 8FC143060289: client=mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/cleanup[11260]: 8FC143060289: message-id=<004601cfd886$f873f540$e95bdfc0$@alrazy@sender.com>
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 opendkim[18460]: 8FC143060289: mail.sender.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.250] not internal
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 opendkim[18460]: 8FC143060289: not authenticated
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 opendkim[18460]: 8FC143060289: no signature data
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/qmgr[7018]: 8FC143060289: from=<g.alrazy@sender.com>, size=11431, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/smtpd[11257]: disconnect from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/virtual[11261]: 8FC143060289: to=<fbl@example.com>, relay=virtual, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Sep 25 06:08:10 bm1 pfix-smtp/qmgr[7018]: 8FC143060289: removed
Sep 25 06:09:31 bm1 pfix-unsub/anvil[11219]: statistics: max connection rate 3/60s for (smtp:XXX.XXX.XXX.42) at Sep 25 06:03:26
Sep 25 06:09:31 bm1 pfix-unsub/anvil[11219]: statistics: max connection count 3 for (smtp:XXX.XXX.XXX.42) at Sep 25 06:03:26
Sep 25 06:09:31 bm1 pfix-unsub/anvil[11219]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Sep 25 06:03:15
Sep 25 06:10:33 bm1 pfix-out2/smtpd[11289]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Sep 25 06:10:33 bm1 pfix-out2/smtpd[11289]: connect from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:10:33 bm1 pfix-out2/smtpd[11289]: setting up TLS connection from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
Sep 25 06:10:33 bm1 pfix-out2/smtpd[11289]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]: TLSv1 with cipher ADH-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Sep 25 06:10:33 bm1 pfix-out2/smtpd[11289]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]: 554 5.7.1 <fbl@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<m.mokhtar@sender.com> to=<fbl@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<sender.com>
Sep 25 06:10:33 bm1 pfix-out2/smtpd[11289]: disconnect from mail.sender.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.250]
```

Notice, that

- 1st test sent to fbl@example.com was processed by pfix-unsub : Relay Access denied
- 2nd test sent to bounce@example.com processed "correctly" by correct instance pfix-smtp
- 3rd test sent to fbl@example.com was processed "correctly" by correct instance pfix-smtp
- 4th test sent to fbl@example.com was processed by pfix-out2 : Relay Access denied

---

**DNS Settings**

```
IN      MX      10      smtp
IN      MX      10      unsub.eg
IN      MX      10      out1.eg
IN      MX      10      out2.eg

;A Records
example.com.                    IN      A       YYY.YYY.YYY.3
subdomain1                      IN      A       YYY.YYY.YYY.3
smtp                            IN      A       XXX.XXX.XXX.123
unsub.eg                        IN      A       XXX.XXX.XXX.124
out1.eg                         IN      A       XXX.XXX.XXX.125
out2.eg                         IN      A       XXX.XXX.XXX.126

;SPF TXT RR
example.com.                   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx:smtp.example.com mx:out1.eg.example.com mx:out2.eg.example.com ~all"

example.com.                   IN      TXT     "spf2.0/pra mx:smtp.example.com mx:out1.eg.example.com mx:out2.eg.example.com ~all"
;DKIM TXT RR
default._domainkey              IN      TXT     "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=**key**"
```

Comment: **Clarification**: (1) when you `telnet smtp.example.com 25` and send an email, do all instances process it together?

Comment: No, just 1, sometimes smtp.example.com picks it up and delivers to mailbox successfully, another time unsub would pickit up and log relay access denied, another time out1 would pickit up and also log relay access denied...and so on.

Comment: How about MX record of your domain example.com . Did it pointing to  ip.address.of.1st.instance?

Comment: Yes, smtp -> .1 unsub -> .2 out1 -> .3 out2 -> .4 I also have this defined in etc/hosts file to cutdown on lookup. I want to also note that master.cf file for each instance has smtp inet n - n - - smtpd in it. I tried to force binding by ip i.e. ip:smtp inet n - n - -smtpd but still no go! same issue persists

Comment: So, your `example.com` has MX record `smtp.example.com` which is has ip address `xxx.xxx.xxx.1`, right? Well, if your smtp setup was fine, then that's the client's responsibility to connect the correct IP address not yours.

Comment: You could say that I'm handling the whole thing from dns setup to mail server setup:) The MX records under example.com are pointing to the correct ips, however when i test send an email to say bounce@example.com or fbl@example.com...any one of the four instances could pick it from queue to try and deliver it (however in the case unsub, ou1, out2 relay access deny is logged, if smtp instance happens to pick it up it gets delievered to mailbox np).

Comment: On the other hand if i send a test email to 123@unsub.eg.example.com it always gets picked up and delivered by the unsub instance only

Comment: Also another question is that why is out1 and out2 processing these emails with mydestination= and different hostname setup in their main.cf etc!?

Comment: Please attach some logs of all your servers and show your DNS-settins (for MX).

Comment: What do you mean *pick it from queue*? Before enter queue, client must passing one of smtpd instances, right? OK,  for make this problem clear, please add (1) the step when you SENT email (telnet/ sendmail/mailclient/script) AND (2) logs of all instance (when they accept or reject)

Comment: @sebix I have re-edited post with logs and MX records. Thanks!

Comment: @masegaloeh I mostly did the tests using outlook mail client to send out the test emails. Thanks!

Comment: Kudos for using `example.com` instead of making up a random name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got all your postfix instances listed as MX for the domain, and with the same weight. This means that sending mail servers can choose whichever one of them they want.

Since you only want `smtp.example.com` to handle incoming mail, you should remove all MX lines except for

```
IN      MX      10      smtp
```

**Edit in response to comments:** The MX records apply specifically to `example.com` - it's effectively saying that "if you want to send an email to any address ending in `@example.com`, you can use any one of the servers listed as MX.

For `unsub.eg.example.com`, you have an A record. When a sending mailserver looks up how to route mails to that address, it will start by looking for an MX record for `unsub.eg.example.com`. If it doesn't find one, it will look for an A record. And since the A record for `unsub.eg.example.com` exists, the message will get sent directly to that server. Thus, you do not need an MX record for it. (And if you did want to use an MX record, it should be set for `unsub.eg.example.com`, not for `example.com`!)

As for the SFP records, those are specifically for **outgoing** traffic. MX is specifically for **incoming** traffic. It's common practice, especially for larger domains, to have separate servers for outgoing traffic vs incoming traffic. In those cases, the outbound servers only should be listed in SFP, and the incoming ones should only be listed as MX.

It's possible to set the SPF record to include all MXes. But it's equally possible to simply list the IP addresses, or A records, of the servers allowed to send mails, regardless of whether the servers are also used as MX or not. More information about the syntax is available at [OpenSPF.org](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)

**Edit 2:** Here's a suggestion for a new SPF record:

```
;SPF TXT RR
example.com.                   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a:out2.eg.example.com a:out1.eg.example.com ~all"
```

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't I define unsub.eg.example.com as MX record to receive emails addressed to username@unsub.eg.example.com as well. Also regarding out1 and out2, shouldn't i define mx records for those as well and include them in SPF RR to validate correctly on SenderID Framework check, as they are outbound mail servers?

Comment: I've made an edit that should answer your questions. In short: no, you do not need MX records for the three other servers.

Comment: Thank you so much Jenny, not only for your solution but explanation that made me better understand setting up DNS records. Thanks also to everyone for your time in investigating this issue! Now, i can sleep again, at least for a short while until the next adventure:)

Comment: You're welcome! Now that I no longer spend all my waking hours herding mail servers, I've started to enjoy solving other people's mail server problems :-)